# Inline on Foreignkey a module further

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have these models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #etc

class Organization(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=OrganizationUser, verbose_name=_('users'))
    #etc

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey('Organization')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to show the  organizations for an user with inline:

```
class UserOrganizationsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrganizationUser

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [UserOrganizationsInline]

admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

The error message is:

```
<class 'customer.models.organization.OrganizationUser'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'customer.models.userprofile.UserProfile'>
```

I know why: Organization has ForeignKey to auth.User instead of modes.UserProfile.

How can i make this work without changing the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough idea (untested): set the `ForeignKey` to `UserProfile` model but reflect the `user_id` field instead of primary key. So you'll have relation to `UserProfile` with the same values in the database as now (`User.id`):

```
class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, to_field='user_id')
```